# Spring Autowired Services Set on Deploy, but Null when called

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, annotations

Sorry if I mess up with my question, I am just getting started configuring MVC, Spring, etc....

The issue that I am running into is that in my Spring MVC project all of my Autowired services are being successfully autowired when my application deploys (verified by setting breakpoints in Spring Tool Suite), but when I try to invoke a autowired service's method I run into a NullPointerException. I have looked all over at different configuration files and it seems like my servelt-context, root-context and web XML files should be ok (don't quote me on that and they are included below).

I am wondering if somehow I am not invoking the instance of the service created at deploy time? It seems strange that the Autowired setters can be called successfully but then the services end up being null.  Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated!

root-context.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.byteslounge.spring.tx.model" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDrive" />
    <property name="url"
        value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@**********" />
    <property name="username" value="*******" />
    <property name="password" value="*******" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />

<context:annotation-config />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.clm.billing" />
```

servelt-context.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>OrderList</display-name>
    <servlet-name>OrderList</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.clm.billing.Oracle.OrderList</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>OrderList</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/OrderList</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>EditBilling</display-name>
    <servlet-name>EditBilling</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.clm.billing.EditBilling</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>EditBilling</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/EditBilling</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>UpdateBilling</display-name>
    <servlet-name>UpdateBilling</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.clm.billing.UpdateBilling</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UpdateBilling</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/UpdateBilling</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

InsuranceNoteDBServiceImpl:
(Here the setiNoteDAO is called with a instance of the iNoteDAO class, but when getNoteById is called iNoteDAO is null)

```
    @Service
public class InsuranceNoteDBServiceImpl implements InsuranceNoteDBService {

    private InsuranceNoteDAO iNoteDAO;

    @Autowired
    public void setiNoteDAO(InsuranceNoteDAO iNoteDAO) {
        this.iNoteDAO = iNoteDAO;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void insertNote(BillerNote note) {
        iNoteDAO.insertNote(note);

    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public BillerNote getNoteById(int noteId) {
        return iNoteDAO.getNoteById(noteId);
    }

}
```

InsuranceNoteDBService:

```
    public interface InsuranceNoteDBService {

    void insertNote(BillerNote note);

    BillerNote getNoteById(int noteId);

}
```

InsuranceNoteDAOImpl:
(Same thing happens here with the init() method that is setting the session factory)

```
@Service
public class InsuranceNoteDAOImpl implements InsuranceNoteDAO {

    public SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public void init(SessionFactory factory) {
        setSessionFactory(factory);
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory factory) {
        this.sessionFactory = factory;
    }

    @Override
    public void insertNote(BillerNote note) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(note);
    }

    @Override
    public BillerNote getNoteById(int noteId) {
        return (BillerNote) sessionFactory.
                  getCurrentSession().
                  get(BillerNote.class, noteId);
    }

}
```

InsuranceNoteDAO:

```
    public interface InsuranceNoteDAO {

    void insertNote(BillerNote note);

    BillerNote getNoteById(int noteId);

}
```

Comment: The setter for iNodeDao seems incorrect. It should be setINodeDao. Did you auto generated the setter or wrote by hand?

Comment: @VaibhavRaj - I did write it by hand instead of having STS generate it, but the name should not matter, it is being called with an instance of InsuranceNoteDAO.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot - I should not have to define beans in the spring context xml, they should be picked up by Spring's pre-processor based on the annotations given to the classes.  This is set up by <context:component-scan base-package="com.clm.billing" />

Comment: Did you mean that you created InsuranceNoteDao instance with new operator and calling setiNodeDao?

Comment: @VaibhavRaj - No, InsuranceNoteDAO is autowired, so there is no need to either of those. I typed the actual setter method instead of using Spring Tool Suite's source code generator. Currently spring is calling the setter and spring is passing it an instance of InsuranceNoteDAO to set iNoteDAO to.

Comment: I see that you have two servlets. Can you confirm that the second servlet `OrderList` does not play any role in your question?

Comment: @PavelHoral - OrderList.java collects user input from a form and has an autowired instance of InsuranceNoteDBService.  The same issue is going on there as well were the service is null if I autowire it.  Right now I removed the Auotwired annotation in order to test the issue that I have documented in my question

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that the autowiring will work only on instances **created by Spring's bean factory**? If you define servlet this way, it will get instantiated by the servlet container.

Comment: If I understand you correctly yes. My application home controller contains:
`
AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("root-context.xml");

context.registerShutdownHook();

OrderListInterface oli = context.getBean(OrderListInterface.class);

oli.start();`

Comment: @grahamcr were you able to find a solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the init method and annotate the setter :

```
@Autowired
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory factory) {
    this.sessionFactory = factory;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I removed the init method as you said and annotated the setter with @Autowired, but still have the same issue as before.